# ! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used

Tags: tables, errors

I'm writing my master thesis and I have a problem with Texstudio. I want to get a table with specific widths, but I get:

```
! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (C): `c' used.
```

I change small `c` to big `C` or `C` to `c`, but it's not working (when I change to `p{3.5cm}` it's good and I get table, but I want centering).

My code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\caption{Distance and temperature}
\label{tab:gr_k}
\begin{tabular}{||C{25mm}|C{40mm}|C{35mm}|C{35mm}||}
\hline
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Person}}& \textbf{Distance} & \textbf{Temperature 1}&                                              \textbf{Temperature 2} \\
                    &\textbf{[cm]} & \textbf{$T_{P1}$ [$^\circ$C]} & \textbf{$T_{P2}$ [$^\circ$C]} \\

\hline
\textbf{1k} & \multirow{4}{*} {100} & 30,983 & 31,351 \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
\textbf{2k} &                       & 29,015 & 29,516  \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
\textbf{3k} &                       & 28,871 & 28,736  \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
\textbf{4k} &                       & 28,278 & 28,512  \\
\hline
\hline
\textbf{1k} & \multirow{4}{*}{100}  & 30,902 & 31,425  \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
\textbf{2k} &                       & 28,910 & 29,480   \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
\textbf{3k} &                       & 28,623 & 28,523   \\
\cline{1-1} \cline{3-4}
\textbf{4k} &                       & 29,878 & 29,413   \\
\hline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! Have you defined `C` somewhere? My guess is not and that's what you need to do. You can define it so it takes an argument for the width, but it is not a default specifier.

Comment: By the way, specifying `h` as the sole position for `table` makes no sense. It means 'put it here if there's space'. So what if there isn't?

Comment: You probably forget (or need) to add `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` to your preamble (after loading [`array`](//ctan.org/pkg/array)).

Comment: Try `\usepackage{array}\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}` in your preamble.

Comment: @Werner I'm 40secs too late :(.

Comment: Thanks :) I try

Comment: Yeah!!!! It's working!!! Thanks, Thanks Warner and cfr :) I can go sleep. If can't help me, I couldn't sleep all night haha, Good night :)

Comment: Please mark for closure